# std::move operation C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move

Lines from Anthony Williams book:

> The following example shows the use of std::move to transfer ownership
>   of a dynamic object into a thread:
>
> ```
> void process_big_object(std::unique_ptr<big_object>);
>
> std::unique_ptr<big_object> p(new big_object);
> p->prepare_data(42);
> std::thread t(process_big_object,std::move(p));
> ```
>
> By specifying `std::move(p)` in the `std::thread` constructor, the
>   ownership of the `big_object` is transferred first into **internal
>   storage** for the newly created thread and then into
>   `process_big_object`.

I understand stack and heap; any idea, what actually is this **internal storage** ?

Why can't they transfer the ownership directly to `process_big_object`?

Comment: each thread has its own stack. The thread object needs to first request the creation of its own stack and other OS resources before it can call your function with its own stack as the base. So it needs to store the data somewhere before dispatching to your function.

Comment: thanks, @PeterT. that answered the last part of my ques.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the object will temporarily belong to the `std::thread` object until the thread actually starts.

Internal storage here refers to the memory associated to the `std::thread` object. It could be a member variable, or just held in the stack during the constructor. Since this is implementation dependant, the general, and non-commital, "internal storage" term is used.

Comment: Both answers equally good. Accepting this one for the last line.

Answer (score 8):

All arguments to a thread are copied into some internal memory held by the `std::thread` object, so it can be passed to the thread function.

That internal memory is owned by the `std::thread` object, before the ownership is passed on to the actual thread function.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't they transfer the ownership directly to `process_big_object`?

Because there is no line in the code snippet where `process_big_object` is called as a function.  The last line of the snippet calls the `std::thread` constructor.  It will set in motion a chain of events that eventually will cause `process_big_object(p)` to be called in the new thread; but that call is not visible here.